# Set forge fuzz.runs in github CI tests

Tags: testing, foundry, forge

I have a test using forge like so:

```
    /**
     * Reduce fuzz runs.
     * forge-config: default.fuzz.runs=10
     */
    function testMyThing(uint256 rng) external {
        // ...
    }
```

When I run this test in the CLI with `forge test` it will correctly limit the run of this function to `10`. When I run the same tests via a github action, it does the full `1024` runs.

GH actions:

```yaml
  forge:
    name: Forge tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [install]
    steps:
      # ...
      - name: Install Foundry
        uses: foundry-rs/foundry-toolchain@v1
        with:
          version: nightly
      # ...
      - name: Run Forge tests
        run: |
          forge test -vvv
        id: test
```

What is the correct way to make this function only do 10 runs consistently across all forge test calls/profiles?